# How python brings functions into scope?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image, coverage.py

I contribute to `scikit-image` and was using `coverage`. Now, when I did

```
coverage run benchmarks/benchmark_name.py
```

and then generated the report, there were a lot of files that didn't have any link to this file but were still executed when I ran the above command. One interesting thing that I noted in those files, only the lines having a function definition(`def abc():`) were run. See the image below:

[image: coverage report of a file]

It basically shows the coverage report of a file which didn't have any link to my file. Yet, it was run and only the function definition statements and import statements.

Is this the way python brings functions defined in the project into its scope? If that's the case, I would like to know the flow in which this happened. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at `import` transitive dependencies. At import time, anything not protected by an `if __name__ == '__main__':` clause will be executed, including the `def` statements that you mentioned.

Use `coverage run --omit=...` and similar options to trim your reporting output.